# Request for bounty on this question about common MS Outlook 2013 problem?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question

I apologise if this request offends or wounds anyone. For the past several months, I've failed to find an answer or resolution to this Outlook 2013 problem: [How to exclude notifications for all junk email? (Outook 2013)](https://superuser.com/q/577221/269574). Please observe that this question is NOT mine.

So would I be allowed to ask whether someone can please place a bounty on it?

My naivety at computer science has minimised my level of reputation, and what little of it remains, I may have to use it for [this current urgent problem](https://superuser.com/q/924973/269574).

Afterword: I asked this on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251191/226001).

Comment: There's an answer on the bountied question. Please review it and leave a comment if it works or not - bounty expires in 3 days

Comment: @Sathya Please see my reply to your comment above, located under your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put a bounty on the question.

Comment: @harrymc Sathya: please allow me to reply to your comment above here, to ensure that user 'harrymc' is informed also. Sorry for the delay; I forgot to try it. I have now. Alas, it doesn't seem to resolve the problem, but I left a comment under that answer. Does it help?

Comment: @harrymc However, 'harrymc' must have consumed some time writing his answer, and i loathe to have a bounty wasted. So please feel free to reward it, if you please.

Comment: @LePressentiment - You cannot ping a user unless they are following the question already having a comment you are replying.  So your last two comments were never received by the user you tried to ping.